# Long Running Kafka Stream Suddenly Died with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka streams application which had been running and processing records for several hours. At some point, all of the threads died with the following message.

```
Exception in thread "MY_STREAM-29fd50b1-1478-4a82-8014-a42a1eabeb28-StreamThread-7" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Assigned partition MY_TOPIC_1-KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000015-repartition-24 for non-subscribed topic regex pattern; subscription pattern is MY_TOPIC_1|MY_TOPIC_2|MY_TOPIC_1_V1-KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000023-repartition|MY_TOPIC_1_V1-KSTREAM-MAP-0000000024-repartition
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignFromSubscribed(SubscriptionState.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:220)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1149)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:827)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:784)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:750)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:720)
```

It appears that this exception was unrelated to any message processing as our exception handler was not called. Restarting the application servers 'fixed' the problem; the streams are running and processing records again. What caused this issue? How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Unclear to me. Sound like a bug. Do you have Kafka Streams and logs in DEBUG mode by any change?

Comment: I don't - but I can put them into DEBUG mode. I'll do that now and will get you the logs if/when this happens again.

Comment: That would be very helpful. Feel free to file a Jira and attach the logs if it happens again.